# Find all .rpt files in VS solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, search, projects-and-solutions

I would like to search my VS 2008 solution and return back all files of .rpt files.

If possible, I would prefer it to be in code. I'd love to iterate over these files.

(This is for some maintenance of a solution that I inherited and has a lot of unreferenced code which I am attempting to clean up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the FileInfo class, loop through all folders and files and build a list of all files with names that end with .rpt

Comment: Good call, [smacks head!] I should have thought of that